# How to find n factorial in C?

Tags: c, factorial

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fac(int m){
    long long int i,s=1;
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        s*=i;
    }
    return s;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",fac(n));
}
```

when I tried to put 13 in n,
the answer was supposed to be 13!, which is 6227020800, but 1932053504 came out.

Comment: Integer overflow? Take a closer look at the difference (in hex) - it's quite self-descriptive.

Comment: When testing your code, I get `1932053504` as answer?  Maybe try to add debugging after the line: `s*=i;`, something like: `printf("%lld %lld \n",s,i);`, and check output.

Comment: Your function return type is `int`, but the variable `s` is of type `long long int`. Can you elaborate on that? And what is the result you expect at `return s`?

Comment: Also worth typing `"[c] factorial"` into the search box at the top of the page...

Comment: Just change the `fac` return type to `long long int`, and using `lld` format to output. You could try it [online](https://onlinegdb.com/54nyPTsaZ).

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `int`, but the value it's trying to return is `long long int`.

Also the `printf` format `%d` expects an int, but you should be passing it a `long long int`. `%ld` is the format for a long int. I don't know how you handle it with `long long int`.  I don't think you need a long long int anywhere in here anyway.